# Create to create a UISearchResultsUpdating view controller in Swift?

Tags: swift, uisearchcontroller, uisearchresultscontroller

I am trying to create a `UISearchResultsUpdating` tableview controller programmatically using Swift.

The `updateSearchResults` doesn't get called, even though I've set the tableview controller as the `searchResultsUpdater` and `searchResultsController` for the searchController, and the tableview controller is the delegate of the searchBar.

What other steps am I missing?